# Sending text range selection to zeroclipboard

Tags: javascript, zeroclipboard

I'm trying to allow the user to copy "rich text" on the page to be pasted into Word / their email program, etc. using Javascript.

To do this, I'm first creating a range selection using this function:

```
function copyHTMLToClipboard($target) {

    var contents = false;

    if (window.getSelection) {
        contents = window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.getSelection) {
        contents = document.getSelection();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        contents = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }

    if (contents && (contents+'').length > 0) {
        return contents;
    }

}

function copy($target) {
    $target.select();
    contents = copyHTMLToClipboard($target);
}
```

I'm then trying to send the output to zeroclipboard like so:

```
$(".zclip").zclip({
    ...
    copy: function() { contents = copy($target); }
    ...
});
```

This throws an error "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Please note that I DO NOT want copied text like:

```
<h1>Something</h1>
<strong>Something else</strong>
```

I want the text to contain rich text (formatted text) that can be pasted into another program like Word/Gmail, etc. Basically what you'd get if you selected text on a page manually and copied it.

What am I doing wrong? Is what I'm trying possible?